# tikz "Latex" arrowhead artifact on conversion to png using ImageMagick if opacity < 1

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-arrows

This is a specific problem, but I find it comes up often in my workflows:

- generate a standalone `tikz` diagram with:

  - some transparent object(s) - i.e. `opacity < 1`
  - arrows, where I prefer the large style: `> = Latex` from the tikz library `arrows.meta`
- run ImageMagick `convert` to convert `.pdf` to `.png`

The problem is, `Latex` style arrowheads develop a weird inner border on conversion to `.png`.

## MWE

mwe.tex:

```
\documentclass[margin=0.1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[>=Latex,<->,opacity=1.00](0.0,-0.0)--(1.0,-0.0); % (1)
  \draw[>=Latex,<->,opacity=0.99](0.0,-0.2)--(1.0,-0.2); % (2)
  \draw[>=latex,<->,opacity=1.00](0.0,-0.4)--(1.0,-0.4); % (3)
  \draw[>=latex,<->,opacity=0.99](0.0,-0.6)--(1.0,-0.6); % (4)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

compile & convert to png:

```
pdflatex mwe.tex && convert -density 600 mwe.pdf mwe.png
```

#### MWE result:

[image: MWE result]

#### About the MWE:

- You can see the problem in arrows (1) and (2), currently
- Arrows (3) and (4) are not affected, since they have the smaller arrowheads: `> = latex`
- Only commenting (2) and (4) (`opacity=0.99`) solves the problem for (1) - i.e. removing all transparent objects from the image.

## Questions:

- Why is this happening?
- Is this a `tikz` problem or an ImageMagick problem?
- Any solutions besides avoiding transparency or using smaller arrowheads?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because these arrows consist of some draw and some fill part. You can avoid it by using a `transparency group`.

```
\documentclass[margin=0.1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=1.00]    
  \draw[>=Latex](0.0,-0.0)--(1.0,-0.0); % (1)
  \draw[>=latex,<->](0.0,-0.4)--(1.0,-0.4); % (3)
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=0.99]
  \draw[>=latex,<->](0.0,-0.6)--(1.0,-0.6); % (4)
  \draw[>=Latex,<->](0.0,-0.2)--(1.0,-0.2); % (2)
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]